# Is it possible to repopulate radio button inputs with values from submission.fieldMetaData using the standard form.render() method?

Tags: plugin-freeform, solspace

I've been able to repopulate text fields this way, but the radio buttons remain unchecked even when there was a value submitted.

```
{% for field in application.fieldMetaData %}
    {% set submittedValues = submittedValues|merge({ (field.handle): attribute(application, field.handle).value}) %}
{% endfor %}

{% if form|length %}
    {{ craft.freeform.form(form.handle, {
      returnUrl: '/',
      overrideValues: submittedValues
    }).render() }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I've discovered that this is not possible. You have to use manual form rendering to do this.

Comment: Glad you found a solution... would you mind adding it as an official answer in case it ends up helping someone in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little messy but here's how I got it to work in case anyone else has this question. It even seems to respect the conditional display rules on my form.

```
{% if form|length %}
    {{ form.renderTag }}

    {% if form.hasErrors %}
      <div class="freeform-form-has-errors">
        {{ "Error! Please review the form and try submitting again."|t('freeform') }}

        {% if form.errors|length %}
          <ul>
            {% for error in form.errors %}
              <li>{{ error }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
          </ul>
        {% endif %}
      </div>
    {% endif %}

    {% for row in form %}
      <div class="freeform-row {{ form.customAttributes.rowClass }}">
        {% for field in row %}
          {% set columnClass = "freeform-column " ~ form.customAttributes.columnClass %}
          {% if field.type == "submit" %}
            {% set columnClass = columnClass ~ " freeform-column-content-align-" ~ field.position %}
          {% endif %}
          {% if field.type == "radio_group" %}
            <div class="{{ columnClass }}"{{ field.rulesHtmlData }}>
                {{ field.renderLabel() }}
                <div class="freeform-instructions">
                 {{ field.renderInstructions() }}
                </div>
                {% if field.errors %}
                <ul class="errors freeform-errors">
                    {% for error in field.errors %}
                        <li>{{ error }}</li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
                {% endif %}
                {% for option in field.options %}
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" class="freeform-input" 
                          name="{{ field.handle }}" type="radio" 
                          id="form-input-{{ field.handle }}-{{ loop.index }}" 
                          value="{{ option.value }}" 
                          {{ option.value == submittedValues[field.handle] ? 'checked' : '' }}>
                        {{ option.label }}
                    </label>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
          {% else %}
          <div class="{{ columnClass }}"{{ field.rulesHtmlData }}>
            {{ field.render({
              class: field.type != "submit" ? "freeform-input" : "",
              labelClass: "freeform-label" ~ (field.inputOnly ? " freeform-input-only-label" : "") ~ (field.required ? " freeform-required" : ""),
              errorClass: "freeform-errors",
              instructionsClass: "freeform-instructions",
              overrideValue: field.handle ? submittedValues[field.handle] : ''
            }) }}
          </div>
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="hidden" name="statusId" value="2">
    <input type="hidden" name="submissionId" value="{{ application.id }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="userId" value="{{ currentUser.id }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="userEmail" value="{{ currentUser.email }}">
    {{ form.renderClosingTag }}
    {% endif %}

{% js %}
    var act = document.getElementsByName('action');
    act[0].value = 'freeform/submissions/save'
{% endjs %}
```